# VS C++ ASM to GCC ASM

Tags: c++, assembly

Did I convert this correctly?

Original VS C++ version:

```
 _TEB *pTeb = NULL;

        _asm
        {
            mov eax, fs:[0x18];
            mov pTeb, eax;
        }
```

My attempt (GCC):

```
 _TEB *pTeb = NULL;

        asm ("movl %%fs:0x18, %%eax\n\t"
             "movl %%eax, %0"
            : "=rm" (pTeb) : : "%eax");
```

Comment: Have you tried testing it to see if it correctly compiles and produces the same results?

Comment: Looks correct to me as long as both run on Windows (ptibSelf in the TIB isn't available elsewhere). If it's a port to another platform, you need to rethink the functionality :)

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I wrote it with my phone and had no compiler to check.

Answer (score 0):

If you need GCC syntax for Windows-related code, a good source to check is [ReactOS](http://www.reactos.org/) sources. Here's their implementation of `NtCurrentTeb()` (with irrelevant parts removed):

```
unsigned long __readfsdword(const unsigned long Offset)
{
    unsigned long value;
    __asm__ __volatile__("movl %%fs:%a[Offset], %k[value]" : [value] "=r" (value) : [Offset] "ir" (Offset));
    return value;
}

struct _TEB * NtCurrentTeb(VOID)
{
  return (PTEB)__readfsdword(0x18);
}
```